# What is causing the '403 Forbidden error' in my Apache2 server? And how can I fix it? The available fixes on the web are not working for me

Tags: django, linux, apache, ubuntu, linode

A little bit of context to my problem... I'm trying to deploy my django application following a **tutorial (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Sa_kQheCnds)** which uses linode to setup a linux apache server, and after following the steps, it always results in the same error, *403 Forbidden: You don't have permission to access this resource*. I've followed the steps in this guide roughly 6 times now and I've determined that I'm definitely not doing anything the guy didn't do.

Something worth mentioning is that in the tutorial, Ubuntu 18.10 is being used, however I don't have Ubuntu 18.10 available, so I've tried it using Ubuntu 18.04, 20.04 and 21.10.

**In my sixth and latest attempt, I am using Ubuntu 21.10**

I've also tried running the server with **DEBUG=True** to see if I can get a little more insight on the error, but it just displays the following:

[image: the error]

The tutorial is very long so I've broken down every single step in this post.

**The steps I had to follow are:**

*(everything done in the Windows Linux Bash shell)*

- **Creating Linode and analizing Ip Address and SSH Credentials I got**
- **Root Connection to the Server**

  `ssh` into the server for the first time
- **Installing Software Updates**

  Running the command `sudo apt-get update && apt-get upgrade`
- **Setting Host Name**

  hostnamectl set-hostname SERVER_NAME

  Then checking if it was rightfully executed with `hostname`
- **Setting Host File**

  `nano /etc/hosts` and then adding the IP address and server name to the file.
- **Adding Limited User**

  The guy in the video said it's not good practice to use root user because it's easy to mess things up like that so we created a limited user with `adduser USER_NAME` and then gave it sudo permissions with `adduser USER_NAME sudo`
- **Setting Up SSH Key Based Authentication**

  In my *local machine's bash shell*:
  `ssh keygen -b 4096`
  And deposit that file into my home folder, after that I copy that file over to *my server* with
  `scp ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub user@serverip:~/.ssh/authorized_keys`
  then lasty confirming it was done correcty *in the server* with
  `ls .ssh`
- **Setting Permissions for SSH Directory**

  Attach certain permision like
  `sudo chmod 700 ~/.ssh/`
  and
  `sudo chmod 600 ~/.ssh/*`
- **Forbiding Root Login & Password Authentication**

  `sudo nano /etc/ssh/sshh_config`
  to forbit *#PermitRootLogin* and *#PasswordAuthentification*
  and then restart with
  `sudo systemctl restart sshd`
- **Setting Up a Firewall**

  First, I install *Uncomplicated Firewall* with
  `sudo apt-get install ufw`
  and then I do the following commands:
  `sudo ufw default allow outgoing` , `sudo ufw default deny incoming` , `sudo ufw allow ssh` and `sudo ufw allow 8000`.
  After that, I enable the firewall with `sudo ufw enable`
- **Generating requirements.txt File**

  Here I actually did it a bit different that in the video. I open my VSCODE environment for the project in question, and then I run a `pip freeze` in the terminal to see if the dependencies are correct, if they are I write the requirements with `pip freeze > requirements.txt`
- **Copying Django Application on to the Webserver**

  This step is pretty straightforward. Just `scp -r /folder/ user@serverip:~/` and that way the folder project is copied into the web server.
- **Creating Virtual Environment on the Server**

  First run a `sudo apt-get install python3-pip` and then `pip install sudo apt-get install python3-venv`. Once that's done, to create my virtual environment I do `python3 -m venv django_project/venv` and lastly I activate it by `cd`ing into the project's folder and then `source venv/bin/activate`.
- **Installing Dependencies**

  With my virtual environment running I run a `pip install -r requirements.txt`
- **Changing Django Settings for Testing the Application on Django Server**

  Inside the project's folder: `sudo nano django_project/settings.py` and add my server's IP to the allowed hosts list, and add a STATIC_ROOT directory.
- **Collecting Static Files**

  `python manage.py collectstatic`
  Which could collect about 120 static files, but my project is a somewhat different from the on in the video because I added way more features so it collects about 137 files *(in case these details are needed)*
- **Testing Application**

  `python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000` and then test to see if there is any problems, there are not *(minus some variables I forgot to add because they were in my PC's environment variables)* so I move on to the next step.
- **Installing Apache & ModWSGI**

  `sudo apt-get install apache2`, `sudo apt-get install libapache2-mod-wsgi-py3`.
- **Configuring Apache Webserver**

  Then move into the apache configuration folder `cd /etc/apache2/sites-available/` and create a new configuration file based off the default one with `sudo cp 000-default.conf django_project.conf`, and then I edit with `sudo nano django_project.conf` it and add the following things to it: https://github.com/CoreyMSchafer/code_snippets/blob/master/Django_Blog/snippets/django_project.conf
- **Enabling Site Through Apache**

  Run the following commands:
  `sudo a2ensite django_project` , `sudo a2dissite 000-default.conf`
- **Setting Up File Permissions**

  Run the following commands:
  `sudo chown :www-date django_project/db.sqlite3` , `sudo chmod 664 django_project/db.sqlite3` and `sudo chown :www-data django_project/. Then` sudo chown -R :www-data django_project/media/`and`sudo chmod -R django_project/media```
- **Creating Configuration File for Hiding Sensitive Information**

  I won't detail this process, I just make a .json file with some secret information like the SECRET_KEY and the email and password.
- **Updating Project Settings File**

  I delete the sentitive information from the settings.py of the project, and instead add those with the .json file (like if it were an environment variable).
- **Allowing http Traffic**

  Run the following commands:
  `sudo ufw delete allow 8000`, and `sudo ufw allow http/tcp`.
- **Restarting the Server & Running the Site**

  `sudo service apache2 restart`

Please, I'd appreciate any kind of help. I have to fix this error for a school project and I can't find solutions that actually fix it. I've read in some forums that I just needed to change certain permissions again, I did that and still the same error. It's really driving me crazy.

Comment: What is the url giving forbidden, also share your Apache config file

Comment: What version of apache2 are you using ?

Comment: @MohamedElKalioby it's just the base URL for the website (just the ip), also, my config file looks exactly like this one https://github.com/CoreyMSchafer/code_snippets/blob/master/Django_Blog/snippets/django_project.conf

Comment: @graylagx2 I'm running apache2.4.48

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found a solution, for now at least. I ran a `sudo chmod 777` on my home folder so that literally every single file is accessible. I heard that this solution was **not recommendable**, but for now it will do.

I still don't know why other solutions that were posted didn't work for me, because it was of my understanding that every file that was needed to fun the server was inside the django_project folder.

I will be looking into it a bit more though, because I don't know how secure it is to have everysingle file with permisions.

Answer (score 2):

you have not done

```
sudo chown :www-data django_project/django_project
```

which is the folder of the wsgi.py script

Comment: Thanks, but I'm sad to say it didn't work. I even ran on the same command on the actual db.sqlite3 file and it's still displaying the same error. Here is a picture of my permissions if It's of any help to you. https://imgur.com/a/QRfSQcW

Answer (score 1):

I think the Forbidden is returned as Apache2 user (www-data) cant reach your HOME folder, move everything to another path like /data or /var/www and give www-data a rx access through the chmod command.

Comment: Any path? Does it not matter?

Comment: Something that www-data can access